# Groovy JsonOutput/JsonBuilder issue with Validatable

Tags: json, grails, groovy

Trying to get the `JsonOutput.toJson(obj)` result for simple object of class inherited from trait `grails.validation.Validateable`:

```
    class Test implements Validateable{
        Long id 
    }
```

And the `stackOverflow` exception is thrown.

While for the following pure class objects:

```
    class TestSimple {
        Long id 
    }
```

everything works fine.

Tested this with `JsonBuilder` as well, the result is the same. Is there any idea how to workaround this?

Comment: I bet this question is about grails (not about plain groovy). And grails has it's own json serializer http://docs.grails.org/3.0.2/api/grails/converters/JSON.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some of the properties added by the `Validateable` trait cause a recursive call chain when serializing to json. I don't have the full root cause analysis here, but in groovy >= 2.5.0 you can doing the following:

```
import grails.validation.*
import groovy.json.*


class Abcdefg implements Validateable {
}

def a = new Abcdefg()

/* 
properties returned by DefaultGroovyMethods.getProperties(a):
  contentHash -> 25e8e25d2e2db8d4c1c300b2dbc5b75c
  originalClassName -> Abcdefg
  class -> class Abcdefg
  errors -> grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors
  constraintsMap -> [contentHash:grails.validation.ConstrainedDelegate@75561c4c, originalClassName:grails.validation.ConstrainedDelegate@771ff7d2]
*/
def generator = new groovy.json.JsonGenerator.Options()
    .excludeFieldsByName('errors', 'constraintsMap')
    .build()

def json = generator.toJson(a)

println(json)
```

which excludes the `errors` and `constraintsMap` properties from the json serialization and removes the StackOverflowException.

Assuming you don't specifically need to serialize the `errors` and `constraintsMap` this might be an option.

If you do, you would have to dig deeper and understand why this is happening.